# Why can't I vote to migrate this question?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, migration

I was thinking of migrating this question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/81842/.

But the migrate option doesn't appear. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's too old. Questions more than 60 days old can't be migrated.